# Data exploration in R: display heatmap of large matrix, quickly?

Tags: r, matlab, matrix, visualization, data-visualization

**How do I quickly visualize large matrices in R?**

I sometimes work with large-ish numeric matrices (e.g. 3000 x 3000), and quickly visualizing them is a very helpful quality control step. This was very easy and fast in Matlab, my previous language of choice. For example, it takes 0.5 seconds to display a 1000x1000 matrix:

```
rand_matrix = rand(1000,1000);
tic
imagesc(rand_matrix)
toc
>> Elapsed time is 0.463903 seconds.
```

I'd like the same powers in R, but unfortunately **visualizing matrices seems very slow in R**. For example, using `image.plot()` the same random matrix takes more than 10 seconds to display:

```
require(tictoc)
require(image.plot)
mm = 1000
nn = 1000
rand.matrix = matrix(runif(mm*nn), ncol=mm, nrow=nn)
tic("Visualizing matrix")
image.plot(rand.matrix)
toc()
> Visualizing matrix: 11.744 sec elapsed
```

The problem gets worse as the matrices get bigger. For example, a 3000x3000 matrix takes minutes to visualize in R, compared to seconds in Matlab. This obviously doesn't really work for data exploration. I've tried ggplot, and melting + geom_raster() can still take up to a minute.

**What am I doing wrong? Is there a fast way to visualize matrices in R?** An ideal solution would take one or two lines.

Comment: Using the builtin `image()` function (just `image(rand.matrix)`) takes 1.75 seconds on my machine, `image.plot()` seems to be slower.

Comment: @Marius `image()` still takes 11.5 seconds on my machine for 1000x1000 matrix, plus a few more seconds for the plot to actually appear. `useRaster=TRUE` speeds it up to 5.4 seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get a plot pretty quickly when using `image(m, useRaster = TRUE)`:

```
start = Sys.time()
image(rand.matrix, useRaster = TRUE)
print(Sys.time() - start)
# Time difference of 0.326 secs
```

Without `useRaster = TRUE` this takes 1.5 seconds, `useRaster` speeds this up but only works for simple, evenly spaced points I think.

If your ultimate goal is to produce an image file with this plot, then I think it might be most efficient to output directly to a raster format like png, although it's a little tricky to measure exactly how long R is taking to save the image file, e.g.:

```
png("image_plot.png", width = 1000, height = 1000)
image(rand.matrix, useRaster = TRUE)
dev.off()
```

Comment: `useRaster=TRUE` speeds things up a lot! I now get 0.2 seconds for 1000x1000, and 1.9 seconds for 3000x3000. However that doesn't account for the whole time, since there's still about ~5-10 seconds until the plot actually appears. Way faster than minutes, though. I'll leave this unanswered in case there's another, faster solution.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why the delay for the plot to actually appear is so long - you might find that's less of an issue if you're outputting directly to a `png()` device.

Comment: How do you output directly to a `png()` device?

Comment: See my edit, I can't 100% guarantee that this gives big efficiency improvements though.

Comment: Saving to file does speed it up, and removes the 5-10s delay while the plot appears in Rstudio. The .png is made almost instantly.