# Speed up rendering of large heatmap from ggplot in R

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, heatmap

I am trying to plot a large heatmap, generated with ggplot, in R. Ultimately, I would like to 'polish' this heat map using Illustrator.

Sample code:

```
# Load packages (tidyverse)
library(tidyverse)

# Create dataframe
df <- expand.grid(x = seq(1,100000), y = seq(1,100000))

# add variable: performance
set.seed(123)
df$z <- rnorm(nrow(df))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = z))
```

Although I save the plot as a vectorized image (.pdf; that is not that large), the pdf is loading very slowly when opening. I expect that every individual point in the data frame is rendered when opening the file.

I have read other posts (e.g. [Data exploration in R: display heatmap of large matrix, quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381307/data-exploration-in-r-display-heatmap-of-large-matrix-quickly)) that use `image()` to visualize matrices, however I would like to use ggplot to modify the image.

**Question:** How do I speed up the rendering of this plot? Is there a way (besides lowering the resolution of the plot), while keeping the image vectorized, to speed this process up? Is it possible to downsample a vectorized ggplot?

Comment: Try using `geom_raster()` instead. Asking the `grid` graphics subsystem to generate that many rectangle objects is not going to end well. Also: ggplo2 makes a copy of all the data before rendering, so this is also eating up an enormous amount of memory until that ggplot2 object goes away. `image()` is very likely the better way to go or one of the non-ggplot2 spatial raster plotting functions.

Comment: Since with that many points you can't actually make sense of individual points, you could bin (either square bins or hex bins) and plot a heatmap.  For outlier points that you want to keep prominent in your plot, filter based on how many points are in a bin.  E.g., if a bin has only 1 point, just plot the point rather than the bin.

Comment: I notice in a recent edit you changed the `expand.grid` from 1e5x1e5 to 1e6x1e6.  This now throws an `cannot allocate vector of size 3725.3 Gb` error.  Suggest rolling back this edit as almost no-one has a computer that size. In fact 1e4x1e4 is already pushing the boundaries.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52912945/visualising-big-set-of-points-with-third-feature-as-a-color-a-way-to-improve-a/53015381#53015381

Comment: Your heatmap is 1M rows x 1M columns, or 1 trillion pixels. At 300 dpi, you would need a display that is 277 feet wide to show that. I presume your screen or page is smaller than that? ;-)

Comment: @dww You are right. I changed it to make a potential solution applicable for people with even larger heat maps, however besides that, it was indeed not a rational change. Thanks for the suggestion, I changed it back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing I tried was `stat_summary_2d` to get average binning, but it seemed slow and also created some artifacts on the right and top edges:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- expand.grid(x = seq(1,1000), y = seq(1,1000))
set.seed(123)
df$z <- rnorm(nrow(df))
print(object.size(df), units = "Mb")
#15.4 Mb

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) +
  stat_summary_2d(bins = c(100,100)) +  #10x downsample, in this case
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 100*0:10) +
  labs(title = "stat_summary_2d, 1000x1000 downsampled to 100x100")
```

Even though this is much smaller than your suggested data, this still took about 3 seconds to plot on my machine, and had artifacts on the top and right edges, I presume due to those bins being smaller ones from the edges, leaving more variation.

[image]

It got slower from there when I tried a larger grid like you are requesting.

(As an aside, it may be worth clarifying that a vector graphic file like a PDF, unlike a raster graphic, can be resized without loss of resolution. However, in this use case, the output is 10,000 megapixel raster file, *far* beyond the limits of human perception, that is getting exported into a vector format, where each "pixel" becomes a very tiny rectangle in the PDF. That use of a vector format could be useful for certain unusual cases, like if you ever need to blow up your heatmap without loss of resolution onto a gigantic surface, like a football field. But it sounds like in this case it might be the wrong tool for the job, since you're putting heaps of data into the vector file that won't be perceptible.)

What worked more efficiently was to do the averaging with `dplyr` before `ggplot`. With that, I could take a 10k x 10k array and downsample it 100x before sending to ggplot. This necessarily reduces the resolution, but I don't understand the value in this use case of preserving resolution beyond human abilities to perceive it.

Here's some code to do the bucketing ourselves and then plot the downsampled version:

```
# Using 10k x 10k array, 1527.1 Mb when initialized
downsample <- 100
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(x = downsample * round(x / downsample),
           y = downsample * round(y / downsample)) %>%
  summarise(z = mean(z))

ggplot(df2, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = z)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1000*0:10) +
  labs(title = "10,000x10,000 downsampled to 100x100")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your reproducible example just shows noise so it's hard to know what kind of output you would like.

One way would be to follow [@dww's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52912945/visualising-big-set-of-points-with-third-feature-as-a-color-a-way-to-improve-a/53015381#53015381) and use `geom_hex` to show aggregated data.

Another way, as you ask "Is it possible to downsample a vectorized ggplot?", is to use `dplyr::sample_frac` or `dplyr::sample_n` in the data argument of your `geom_raster`. I have to take a smaller sample than in your example though or I can't build the df.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Create dataframe
df <- expand.grid(x = seq(1,1000), y = seq(1,1000))

# add variable: performance
set.seed(123)
df$z <- rnorm(nrow(df))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = z), . %>% sample_frac(0.1))
```

If you want to start from your high resolution ggplot object you can do for the same effect:

```
gg <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = z)) 

gg$data <-  sample_frac(gg$data,0.1)
gg
```

[image]