# Plotting / rendering a massive heatmap using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graphics, plotly

So I have tried everything I could think of, and after a few days of searching, I resort to asking here.

I wrote a maze solver in c++, it takes a png image, reads it as binary data, and then solves it. the final output of this solving stage is a matrix with all values set to 0 (walls and unexplored vertices of the maze), except the relevant path. R reads this matrix through Rcpp.

My algorithm itself is quite fast, solving a 10K X 10K maze I found online (weighs 127 megabytes of 16 bit integers) in 0.7 seconds, it also solved a 30k x 30k maze which is the largest I managed to load into memory without Rstudio crashing. (By saying solved, I mean that the output is an ordered sequence  of all (x,y) coordinates on the path from the start to the exit).

Now the thing is that  I want to look at this plot, preferably through something like a 2d heatmap plot, something which i have done on smaller mazes, but with this size of maze - every library I tried to plot with, just crashed my client.
So the question is, is there any way for me to plot a 10K x 10K 2d heatmap in R? (don't mind having it cropped when I zoom out.)

Example code:

```
library(plotly)
mat = matrix(sample(0:1,100000000,replace = T),10000,10000)
plot_ly(z =~ mat, type = "heatmap")
```

Comment: Please add code that you have tried, saying "every library I tried to plot with, just crashed my client" doesn't help us to help. Also, please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889540/speed-up-rendering-of-large-heatmap-from-ggplot-in-r

Comment: @PoGibas I guess I thought the problem was so simple to recreate that no example would be required. Added example code.

Comment: Maybe chunk the matrix `n` rows at a time, plot those, and then stitch those plots together externally? (Or even just chunk into largest possible submatrices.)

Comment: Have you considered sparse matrices? I can image that from the parametrisation of triplet formatted sparse matrices it is quite easy to plot the solution path. I would recommend the `Matrix` package for this.

Comment: Try plotting it as a pixel matrix, rather than with `ggplot`.  [See the examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638462/r-image-of-a-pixel-matrix)

Comment: It will probably still take quite some time to actually render the image though, considering the size.